# How to solve this integral with contour integration $\int ^{\infty }_{0}\frac{\ln( x)}{( x+1)^{\alpha}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

I know how to solve this integral without contour integration. The answer to the integral is

$$\int^{\infty }_{0}\frac{\ln( z)}{( z+1)^{\alpha}} \,dx=\frac{H_{\alpha-2}}{1-\alpha} ,\; \alpha>1,$$ where $H_k$ is the Harmonic number function, and $\alpha$ is not limited to the integers.

To solve it without contour integration I used Feynman's technique. But I know that there are branch points at $z=0, -1$ in the integrand. So it looks like I should be able to solve it with contour integration. But I couldn't. I tried using this contour

[image]

but was unable to get the wanted integral when integrating around the contour. It makes me think that I would need to insert another natural log into the integrand to add another branch point (so that with the argument limiting, I would get my integral back), But I already have two branch points so I'm not sure if that would work. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you don't require $n$ to be an integer, it would be good to explicitly state that (or use a symbol like $\alpha$ that doesn't strongly suggest integers). For integer $n$, there's just a pole at $-1$, simplifying things. Anyway, the usual way to do this via contour integration is to integrate $\frac{(\ln z)^2}{(z+1)^n}$ over the (double) keyhole contour. That doesn't introduce a new branch point.

Comment: So does the argument limitation only effect one natural log then, or both?

Comment: When we approach $(0,+\infty)$ from the lower half plane, the limit of $(\ln z)^2$ becomes $(\ln x + 2\pi i)^2 = (\ln x)^2 + 4\pi i \ln x - 4\pi^2$. The $(\ln x)^2$ is cancelled by the limit of $(\ln z)^2$ from the upper half-plane. The $4\pi i \ln x$ is — except for the constant factor — the thing you want. The $4\pi^2$ part can in this case be elementarily evaluated (generally, that can be evaluated via $\int R(z)\ln z\,dz$ over a keyhole contour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\ge 2$ and let $f(z)=\frac{\log^2(z)}{(z+1)^n}$.  Note that $f$ has a branch point at $z=0$ and a simple pole at $z=-1$.  Cut the plane from $z=0$ to $z=\infty$, along the positive real axis.

The residue theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\log^2(x)-(\log(x)+i2\pi)^2}{(x+1)^n}\,dx&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2(z)}{(z+1)^n}, z=-1\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to -1}\frac{d^{n-1}\log^2(z)}{dz^{n-1}}\\\\
&=\frac{4\pi i}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to -1}\frac{d^{n-2}\left(z^{-1}\log(z)\right)}{dz^{n-2}}\\\\
&=\frac{4\pi i}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to -1}\left(\frac{(-1)^n(n-2)!\log(z)}{z^{n-1}}\\+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}\frac{d^k\log(z)}{dx^k}\frac{d^{n-2-k}x^{-1}}{dz^{n-2-k}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{4\pi i}{n-1}\left(-i\pi+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac1k\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

Simplifying $(1)$ recovers the expected result for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\ge2$

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{(x+1)^n}\,dx=\frac{H_{n-2}}{1-n}$$

Comment: So why then even though there is a branch point if $n$ is a non integer value, it doesn't effect the answer? And yes I see that you solved it based on $n∈N, n≥2$. But my answer is the same and applies to all $n>1$, you just have to us the digamma function's relation to the Harmonic number function for $n$ is a non-integer.

Comment: If the relationship holds for all real $\alpha>1$ then certainly it holds for natural numbers greater than $1$.  If $n$ is not an integer, then the singularity at $z=-1$ us a branch point, not a pole.

Comment: Yes that's what I said, but my question is why does the your method still hold even if  at $z=-1$ there is a branch point instead of a pole when $n\notin \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The method used here needs to be augmented a bit.  If $n$ is not a natural number then we need to cut the plane as in the diagram that you provided.  The integration around the branch cut along the real axis is no longer equal to $2\pi I$ times the residue of $f$ since there is no enclosed singularities.  Instead that integral is equal to the integral in the left half plane (i.e., around the second branch cut and deformed around the branch point at $z=-1$).  Evaluation of that integral might be non-trivial.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought I would have to do. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @Highvoltagemath You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that the integration around the branch cut at $z=-1$ involves three improper integrals (along both sides of the branch cut AND around the branch point), none of which converges on its own.  The sum of the three does (and of course must) converge in terms of Cauchy Principal Value.  However, the native form of these integrals does not render a trivial evaluation.  To date, I have not been able to directly evaluate the sum of the three integrals.

Comment: @MarkViola You're right. I tried to do that but it's a cumbersome task. So, I left it. Maybe, later.

Comment: Hi Felix my friend!  I hope you're doing well and safe and healthy.